# Mockito - mock method call just for particular parameter

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I want to mock a method call for a specific parameter and call the real method for the others.
I have:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("mvntest")
public class OKMMoveMergeTest {
    @MockBean
    private FolderDAO folderDAO;
    ...

    @Test
    public void callDocCreateEp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(folderDAO).getFoldersHierarchy(any(EHierarchyType.class));
        Mockito.doReturn(screwedHierarchy).when(folderDAO).getFoldersHierarchy(EHierarchyType.CLIENT_DOC);

        ...
    }
}
```

With this, I get mocked result for `folderDAO.getFoldersHierarchy(EHierarchyType.CLIENT_DOC)` but when I try to call it with any other parameter I get `NullPointerException`

so what am I doing wrong or how should I stub the method call just for a particular parameter?

junit-jupiter-api: 5.4.0

junit-jupiter-engine: 5.4.0

spring-boot: 2.1.4.RELEASE
mockito-junit-jupiter: 2.23.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Spy for your bean instead of Mock. You can use @SpyBean annotation. This will create a Spy and put it into the context the same way @MockBean does it. In the case of Spy you will have a real object behind it, but you will still be able to override the behaviour if needed as if you had a mock. For examples see the following [article](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16943/Spring-Boot-14--MockBean-and-SpyBean/24301#.XmkT9y17HyU)

Comment: i have `any(EHierarchyType.class)` for matcher

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. In your case you should use Spies - https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy. In that way you will have real object there and you can track every invocation and override particular cases if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way. What more, you can see I'm using `@MockBean` because I need this mock in the application context. not sure how would it work with spy. also at some point I need to reset the mock to behave as regular bean during the sa me test.

Comment: you can use @SpyBean (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) in that case and override a particular argument in a particular test case. This will create a spy and put it into the context.

Comment: actually you're right. it was enough to replace `@MockBean` with `@SpyBean`. post it as an answer and I will accept it.